# Nodejs URL path unquoting reserved characters in pathname (sometimes)

Tags: node.js, cloudflare-workers

this is kinda weird (node repl v8.15.0):

```
let URL = require('url').URL
let {pathname} = new URL('https://my.domain.com/e30%3D/with%3F')
console.log(pathname) // logs '/e30%3D/with%3F' <-- this looks right
```

then in my CloudFlare worker (using the [`service-worker-mock`](https://github.com/pinterest/service-workers)):

```
let URL = require('url').URL
let {pathname} = new URL('https://my.domain.com/e30%3D/with%3F')
console.log(pathname) // logs '/e30=/abc%21%3Fdef' <-- `=` unquoted in path?
```

I'm guessing it's probably a different version of `URL`? Anyway I can control that?

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation that the two URL implementations parse the same way is actually correct, if you open the inspector and run the second code it should encode the way you expect. Unfortunately, as [Harris](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/bug-inconsistent-url-behaviour/98044/9) points out, the Workers URL implementation is buggy and difficult to fix. I'd recommend using some sort of [URL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-url) [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-url) in your code to encode URLs properly.